# Why doesn't my JScrollPane shows my JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, layout-manager

I have a JPanel and I want it to be able to be scrolled, so I am adding it to a JScrollPane, but my JScrollPane doesn't show my Panel completely. just a very small corner of it is shown  and it doesn't scrollit either. But when I only add the LPanel to my JFrame, it is shown correctly!
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Info about my code:

- LPanel is extended from JPanel and I have override the paint. but as
  I said, the paint works fine! it has it's own width and height that
  are 2^k.
- k is the number of rows in my panel.

This is my code:

```
public class Graphics extends JFrame {
  LPanel panel;
  int k;
  public Graphics(int k1) {
    setLayout(null);
    this.k = k1;
    panel = new LPanel(k);
    panel.setSize(panel.width * 30, panel.height * 30);
    new CoveringwithLs(k, panel);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    pane.setLocation(20, 20);
    if (k < 4) {
      pane.setSize(panel.width * 30, panel.height * 30);
      this.setSize(panel.width * 30 + 80, panel.height * 30 + 80);
    } else {
      pane.setSize(panel.width * 30, 600);
      this.setSize(panel.width * 30 + 80, 600);
    }
    getContentPane().add(pane);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Graphics(3);
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `setLayout(null);`  Remove that nonsense, to start with.

Comment: And don't forget to `pack()`.

Comment: I cant add an example, since I'm new and don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: *"I cant add an example,"*  The code above suggests you already did add code!  Just change that code to an SSCCE by [editing the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15998665/edit).

Comment: I meant a picture of an actual run!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cant add an example,

Of course you can. You already have. Now what you need to do is follow the advice given and use layout managers instead of a null layout.

> LPanel is extended from JPanel and I have override the paint.

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method, not the paint() method.

> it has it's own width and height that are 2^k.

You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your panel to return the dimension. Then the scrollpane will function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the scrolls to the ScrollPane. e.g.

```
 JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: it doen't even show my panel comletely!! only a 10 pixels* 10 pixels square of it's up left corner :(

Answer (score -1):

You need to [set the preferred size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) for your JPanel, otherwise the JScrollPane does not know how big is the component it needs to support with its scroll bars. `setSize` has a different purpose and in this cas is not enough.

Comment: -1, you should NOT set the preferred size. As has already been mentioned the preferred approach is to override the getPreferredSize() method. Also, your link is wrong.

Comment: Seems unnecessary "wise" to override the getter instead of using the standard provided setter, if the preferred size can be known. The link is now corrected.

Comment: When you create a custom component, which is basically what you are doing when you do custom painting, then the logic for rendering the component should be self contained. That is the component itself show know what its preferred size should be, which is why you override the getPreferredSize() method. You should not leave it up to the programmer to randomly pick a size of the component.

Comment: Disagree, I really would not want in my library a JList or JTextArea that has its own immutable opinion about which size it should be. At most, the component could compute the default prepared size if none is set like JLabel does.

Comment: `At most, the component could compute the default prepared size` - Exactly. That is the way Swing was designed to work and that is why you override the getPreferredSize() method. That is why JList has `setVisibleRows()` method, or JTextArea allows you to specify the row/columns to display. Then a preferred size can be calculated based on the current Font, renderer or whatever else is required to determine an appropriate size. This is how Swing becomes cross platform.